# RSpec. How to color the piped or redirected output?

Tags: ruby, rspec, bdd

In versions of RSpec before 2.0 I could pipe the color output to less or redirect it to a file. In order to do it I simply have to set the RSPEC_COLOR environment variable to true. However, in the new main version of the framework this variable has stopped to define the output type (color or monchrome). Is there any way to pipe or redirect the color in RSpec 2.0 and higher?

Thanks.

Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.7;

Ruby 1.9.2;

RSpec 2.4.0.

**Updated**

---

I found the answer by myself.

One should use the `tty` configuration option to achieve the effect.

Here's the example:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.tty = true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer in the question is the correct one:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.tty = true
end
```

Then `rspec | grep --color="never" something` keeps the coloring.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the [sources](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb), it seems that the `color_enabled` configuration option is now in the Configuration module of RSpec. However, if the output is not done to a tty, [color is disabled](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb#L225).

My suggestion would be to set `color_enabled = true` and to monkey patch the RSpec Configuration module so that is works even when not outputting to a tty:

```
module RSpec   
  module Core
    class Configuration
      def color_enabled
        true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is not the nicest way, though. This is also untested and I think that monkey patching rspec is not the easiest thing to do because usually tests are run via the dedicated command line tool.

Maybe you could open a bug report to the maintainer and ask for a `force_color_enabled` option ? It would probably be very quick to implement...

Good Luck and Happy Coding !

Comment: Thank you for the answer, **Oct**. I tackle it by myself. See the **Updated** section in my answer.

Comment: By the way, I had an [issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/326) opened on Github, but I got no answer and had to find the solution on my own.

Comment: It works great with this config setting! Just to add, a later, relevant [issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/665) here.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.color_enabled = true
end
```

Comment: **Sam**, the question wasn't about how to color output, but how to preserve color tags when you redirect the ouput to pagers or files. Look: `config.color_enabled = true`; `$ rspec spec/ | less #=> monochrome` but `config.tty = true; config.color_enabled = true`; `$ rspec spec/ | less #=> color`.